# problems plotting tan() with SymPy

Tags: sympy

I'm trying to plot various trig functions with sympy. This works fine with sine, cosine, etc., but tan() displays wierd results. Furthermore, if I rerun just the plot() function, then I get a different result each time.

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.functions.elementary.trigonometric import tan
from sympy.plotting.plot import plot

x = symbols('x')
eqn = tan(x)
plot(eqn, (x, -10, 10))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that this is not how one usually visualizes the tangent function:

[image: tan1]

but it's not wrong. SymPy found that there are extremely large y-values, and chose the vertical scale accordingly. On this scale, all values are practically zero except in close proximity to the singularities. And the unequal height of spikes near singularities is because the evaluation points are not going to hit any `pi/2 + pi*n` exactly, and how close they come depends on what `n` is.

All that said, you need a sane vertical scale, enforced with `ylim`:

```
plot(eqn, (x, -10, 10), ylim=(-20, 20))
```

[image: tan2]